# How to get the name of view programatically such as whether it's textview or button by View params in onClick callback in Android?

Tags: android

In particular class, from many places call back is coming, i just want to whether it's coming text or button for example, so that I can set the data accordingly.

NOTE: I'm not talking about parent layout, I want to know exact name where the event click is happened!

If I'm doing this: `Log.d("Hello", "Clicked finally: "+ view?.id)`

This is coming:

```
D: Clicked finally: 2131296625
```

Comment: You can compare this id with your view id like `view?.id== R.id.button`

Comment: @AlphaOne I know that, but I want to do it in bulk. like from whenever  from any class id button is coming that it'll go to if condition, otherwise else. In short I'm actually interested to know that exact view name, like LinearLatyout, or AppCompatImageButton

Comment: @Sychi Singh I think you can do it using the answer I posted. Please mark the answer as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Kotlin, You can simply check if the View is `Button` or `Image` using `is` operator like:

```
when(view) {

    is Button -> {
       // a Button is clicked.
      }

    is AppCompatImageView -> {
     // an Image is clicked.
     }

    else -> {
    // any other view is clicked.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```kotlin
if (view.javaClass.simpleName == Button::class.java.simpleName) {
   // it is a button
} else if (view.javaClass.simpleName == TextView::class.java.simpleName) {
   // it is a text view        
}
```

Please note that this won't work if you are using any subclass of `Button` or `TextView`. You will need to explicitly specify the class you want to check for.

Comment: suppose I'm using "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView" then how can I do that?

Comment: You can use `AppCompatImageView::class.java.simplename`. You can also compare name property if you prefer full name.